# Conditionally invoking JavaScript from a bean

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

How do I conditionally invoke JavaScript from a bean in JSF 2?

I have a class that uses PrimeFaces which uploads user files to a particular folder, but if the user attempts to upload a file with the same name as one that is already present, I want JavaScript in this case to open up a box on the screen asking the user if he wants to overwrite the old file, or cancel the operation.  If no file with that name is present, then JavaScript is not called.

I know how to test that a folder has a particular file in it, it is just that I need to know how to invoke JavaScript conditionally.

I would most appreciate any advice on this.

---

I have looked at variopus resources online, but still cannot get the application to work correctly.  basically, this is what I have done, in an included xhtml page I have the following code for the file upload:

```
<p:fileUpload id="fileUpload" fileUploadListener="#{filters.upload}"
   allowTypes="#{filters.uploadTypes}" invalidFileMessage="#{filters.uploadBadType}"
   sizeLimit="#{filters.uploadSize}" invalidSizeMessag="#{filters.uploadBadSize}"
   update="fileUpload fileTable uploadMessage" description="Select Text File"
   disabled="#{filters.disableFileUploadButton}"/>

<!--- Then further in the same file is this: -->

<p:remoteCommand name="remoteCommandOverwrite" actionListender="#{filters.execOverwrite}"/>
```

The parent xhtml page that includes the above I have the foolowing JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function popupConfirm() {
    var overwrite = confirm('Warning: This will overwrite the existing file - Do you confirm this?');
    if (overwrite) remoteCommandOverwrite([{name: overwrite, value: true}]);
  }
</script>
```

In my bean I have the following code in three methods:

```
    public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Success! ", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");  
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    overwrite = false;
    // Do what you want with the file        
    try {
        copyFile(event.getFile().getFileName(), event.getFile().getInputstream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public void copyFile(String fileName, InputStream in) {

     // Initialization etc.

                    File file = new File(uploadFull + fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("popupConfirm()");

// Then test to see if overwrite is true or false, and act accordingly

}

// Then I am supposed to get the value of overwrite here:
public void execOverwrite() {
    System.out.println("### execOverwrite() ###");
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, String> map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String soverwrite = (String) map.get("overwrite");
    if (soverwrite.equals("true")) {
        overwrite = true;
        System.out.println("overwrite: true");
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is first to invoke conditionally the JavaScript function popupConfirm().  On clicking the "Upload" button that is invoked if the codition is true, which is what I want.  This is then supposed to call

That works and brings up the confirm() box, but the  is never called, so the method execOverwrite() in my bean is also never called, and I cannot pick up the return value and pass it to the code inside the method copyFile().  What is going wrong?

---

I put this problem on the back burner for about a week, and have just got back to it.  I got it to work, and can pass a value back to the bean, but somehow I need to resume execution from the place where JavaScript is called.

To sumarize, my JavaScript contains the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function popupConfirm() {
    var overwrite = confirm('Warning: This will overwrite the existing file - Do you confirm this?');
    if (overwrite) remoteCommandOverwrite([{name: 'overwrite', value: 'true'}]);
  }
 </script>
```

And in the xhtml code I have:

```
<p:fileUpload id="fileUpload" fileUploadListener="#{filters.upload}" ...../>

<!-- Other code -->

<p:remoteCommand name="remoteCommandOverwrite" actionListener="#{filters.execOverwrite}"/>
```

Then on clicking the file upload button after clicking the choose file button, the code in the JavaScript, as listed above, is executed:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("popupConfirm()");
```

Then on clicking "OK" in the dialog box, this method in the same bean is called:

```
public void execOverwrite() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, String> map = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String soverwrite = map.get("overwrite");
    if (soverwrite.equals("true")) {
        overwrite = true;       }
    }
}
```

where the flag "overwrite" will eventually be tested to see if it is true.

Using various print statements I check that this works.  However, the code does not resume executing after encountering the statement: RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("popupConfirm()"); regardless of whether I enter "OK" or "Cancel" in the dialog, which is what i want it to do.  It looks as if a callback of some type is required, and would most appreciate some ideas.

Comment: I have the same problem with Primefaces 5.1 and JSF 2.2.6. . you have the solution?

Answer (score 2):

According to your tag, you are using PrimeFaces, so there is an easy way to invoke a javascript function from a server side event managed bean method when the browser has completed processing the server response.  PrimeFaces gives you a utility class called `RequestContext`.

```
public void doActionListenerMethod() {
  if (!isValid()) {
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("MyJSObject.doClientSideStuff()");
  }
}
```

The following will execute the string argument as a Javascript when JSF has finished rendering on the client.

Comment: OK, many thanks, I got that to work with a simple alert() box that pops up as a quick test.  Now I need to use a confirm() box that appears, and depending on the whether the user clicks "OK" or "Cancel", the file is uploaded or the upload is cancelled.  Somehow this must be passed back to the bean from JavaScript.

Comment: @csharp Well if you use PrimeFaces dialogs then you can specify a `widgetVar` which is a Javascript variable, and they also have a `show()` and `hide()` function for client side.  Honestly what I would probably do is just upload the file into a session variable right away so it is sitting in server memory.  I would then within a form inside the dialog, I would have the OK and Cancel buttons as JSF commandButtons that invoke server events to either save the file or toss it from the session context if cancelled. The `oncomplete` attribute of `<p:commandButton>` can call the `hide()` JS function

Comment: OK, that is helpful, but I want to keep it as simple as possible.  How do I return a value from a call like RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("confirm('Warning: This will delete all uploaded files - Do you confirm this?')"); where the "confirm()" box opens, then depending on how the user replies, either true or false is returned.  How do I pick up the returned value from RequestContext then act accordingly?

Comment: @csharp You would have to write a Javascript function that invokes the confirm box then, and then depending on the user result you can call p:remoteCommand.  See [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf) for an example of how you can use remoteCommand to do this as simply as possible.